# Passing List of Objects in Command Line Python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a argument to command line for running a python program which takes list of Field Objects and send an email.

The program is running fine when the list of objects is already set in my program.

```
a=[{"name": "productname_0", "type": "html", "content": "A Cool Shirt"}, {"name": "productname_1", "type": "html", "content": "Some Nice Shoes"}, {"name": "productname_2", "type": "html", "content": "A Trendy Hat"}, {"name": "productprice_0", "type": "html", "content": "20.99"}, {"name": "productprice_1", "type": "html", "content": "50.99"}, {"name": "productprice_2", "type": "html", "content": "FREE"}]

sendmail(a)
```

But when I pass this list in command line, it did not work for me.

```
a =sys.argv[1]
sendmail(a)
```

Running Program from Command Line

```
mailscript.py [{"name": "productname_0", "type": "html", "content": "A Cool Shirt"}, {"name": "productname_1", "type": "html", "content": "Some Nice Shoes"}, {"name": "productname_2", "type": "html", "content": "A Trendy Hat"}, {"name": "productprice_0", "type": "html", "content": "20.99"}, {"name": "productprice_1", "type": "html", "content": "50.99"}, {"name": "productprice_2", "type": "html", "content": "FREE"}]
```

Comment: Did you try `python mailscript.py [{"name": "productname_0", "type": "html", "content": "A Cool Shirt"}, {"name": "productname_1", "type": "html", "content": "Some Nice Shoes"}, {"name": "productname_2", "type": "html", "content": "A Trendy Hat"}, {"name": "productprice_0", "type": "html", "content": "20.99"}, {"name": "productprice_1", "type": "html", "content": "50.99"}, {"name": "productprice_2", "type": "html", "content": "FREE"}]` ?

Comment: Passed arguments are always strings. You don't get a list in `argv` because the input looks like a list. You'd need to [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list) the string as a list first.

Comment: You may have to do some quoting.escaoping of for example “ and > in the commandline - start by printing what the arguments passed are and sort out the quoting so the printout is the string you need, then sort out the parsing of it into an actual lPython list.

Comment: The type using argv to acquire value are `str` (you can use `type` to check) and need to parse the value back.  In this case the str can be parse back to list of dict using `json.loads`

Comment: Because your data only uses double quotation marks, you can use single quotation marks to quote the whole thing like this: `mailscript.py '[{....}]'`.

Comment: Hi @Divik, Itried json.loads but it says "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: Hello @adnan can you provide the value of `argv` variable using `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: '[{name:productname_0,       This is the value i am getting on print that variable

Comment: @adnan It looks like your argument are being cut so `json.loads()` fails.  Try to send the argument completely(maybe it's the teminal character limit, etc).

Comment: Any idea, what's causing this ? I am simply copying these commands on Command Line

Answer (score 0):

Inside your program use:

```
a = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
sendmail(a)
```

Execute your program as :

```
python mailscript.py '[{"name": "productname_0", "type": "html", "content": "A Cool Shirt"}, {"name": "productname_1", "type": "html", "content": "Some Nice Shoes"}, {"name": "productname_2", "type": "html", "content": "A Trendy Hat"}, {"name": "productprice_0", "type": "html", "content": "20.99"}, {"name": "productprice_1", "type": "html", "content": "50.99"}, {"name": "productprice_2", "type": "html", "content": "FREE"}]'
```

Comment: I tried this but it says      
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: What is the version of your python?

Comment: Python Version :3.8.5

Comment: If you are executing it from PyCharm, then came out of it and execute it from command-line.

Comment: Which Python Version you are using?